# Watson knowledge studio Custom Model returns only few relations where I have annotate multiple relations?

Tags: machine-learning, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, ibm-watson, watson, watson-knowledge-studio

I am working on Watson Knowledge Studio and build a custom model on it but I have declared many relations for my documents and my every document is different from another .....after that, I have successfully deployed the model on NLU .. but it returns very few relations. Is there any limit for returning relations.

Comment: Are you getting all the entities in the response, but not just the relationship between those entities or both the entities and relations are missing from the response. If it's the second case, could you plz check the case sensitivity of the Entities that you have defined in the documents for your model? I remember when I started developing models on WKS, I had only a couple of documents with most entities in upper case. So when I entered text with different case texts, it didn't even recognise the entities properly and same goes for relations between those entities.

Comment: @MrutyunjayaJena Thank you for your reply I will do the changes in my model as per your suggestions. Will update you..

Comment: @MrutyunjayaJena I tried your suggestions but it won't work my entities are case sensitive but that will be assigned to another entity automatically after my training. I am not getting why this error is coming.

Comment: @Abhijeet, are you saying that, it's not even able to identify all the Entities which you've defined in your model? You've mentioned that the entities that you defined are case sensitive, so the model is not able to identify the entities even when given in the same case as the mentioned documents.

Comment: @MrutyunjayaJena Entities get confused with other entities due to mixed examples are there in my dataset. I am working on Answer verification system for that I need to train the model for multiple different questions.Is watson knowledge studio able to solve my problem.

Comment: @MrutyunjayaJena please check it ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49420928/watson-knowledge-studio-got-confused-between-entities-is-there-any-solution-to-r

Answer (score 0):

If you have not manually specified any limit, you could check your annotations to see why you are getting poor performance. You can check how many relation types you have annotated and if you have given sufficient examples for each relation type. A very complex system is likely to perform poorly, as the back-end contains a ML model which tries to learn from training data. You may consider experimenting by simplifying your type system, with fewer types and sufficient examples for each type.

Comment: But we have mixed data to feed the model ... Will Watson knowledge studio accepts mixed data to build a perfect model..