# Watson Knowledge studio getting confused between Entities

Tags: machine-learning, ibm-cloud, watson-knowledge-studio

**Updated Question:**

I am working on a system which will evaluate user's answers. There are multiple questions with multiple answers to each question which are the possible different ways in which a user can answer that particular question.

For this, I have uploaded multiple different documents containing answers on WKS.  My problem is that my entities are different in one document than entities in other documents and due to which the relations that I have assigned are not working properly. I have tagged it correctly but after training the WKS model this is not working and I am getting confused entities (i.e. entities from answers which belong to a different question are being fetched).

In other words, some entities got confused between other documents entities.

I want to ask whether WKS can resolve my problem in the above scenario of mixed entities and if yes then how?

Note: We are using Watson Knowledge Studio (machine learning model) with NLU

[This image shows the F1 score](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kT4AT.png)

[This image shows the entities got confused](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqYDf.png)

[here the entity does not show relations due to confusion between another entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9tNg.png)

Comment: This question is a duplicate of this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49616367/entities-are-getting-confused-in-watson-knowledge-studio

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying do works that well. WKS (and probably other ML models as well) need sufficient training data in order to classify a certain entity correctly. If you supply it with training documents where the same entity means different things, then obviously this is confusing. To me it sounds like you should either create additional entities or be more specific on the training documents.
Maybe some more examples would help to better understand your scenario. It's pretty difficult to get it from the descriptions and screenshots.